# array of ints remains undef after multiple push() calls

Tags: arrays, perl, system-calls

I'm trying to save error codes by:

```
#global space
my @retCodes;

#main
sub BuildInit {

    my $actionStr = "";
    my $compStr   = "";

    my @component_dirs;
    my @compToBeBuilt;
    foreach my $comp (@compList) {
        @component_dirs = GetDirs($comp);    #populates @component_dirs
    }

    print "Printing Action List: @actionList\n";

    #---------------------------------------
    #----   Setup Worker Threads  ----------
    for ( 1 .. NUM_WORKERS ) {
        async {
            while ( defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() ) ) {
                worker($job);
            }
        };
    }

    #-----------------------------------
    #----   Enqueue The Work  ----------
    for my $action (@actionList) {
        my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new(0);
        $q->enqueue( [ $_, $action, $sem ] ) for @component_dirs;

        $sem->down( scalar @component_dirs );
        print "\n------>> Waiting for prior actions to finish up... <<------\n";
    }

    # Nothing more to do - notify the Queue that we're not adding anything else
    $q->end();
    $_->join() for threads->list();

    return 0;
}

#worker
sub worker {
    my ($job) = @_;
    my ( $component, $action, $sem ) = @$job;
    Build( $component, $action );
    $sem->up();
}

#builder method
sub Build {

    my ( $comp, $action ) = @_;
    my $cmd     = "$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/$comp ";
    my $retCode = -1;

    given ($action) {
        when ("depend") { $cmd .= "$action >nul 2>&1" }    #suppress output
        when ("clean")  { $cmd .= $action }
        when ("build")  { $cmd .= 'l1' }
        when ("link")   { $cmd .= '' }                     #add nothing; default is to link
        default { die "Action: $action is unknown to me." }
    }

    print "\n\t\t*** Performing Action: \'$cmd\' on $comp ***" if $verbose;

    if ( $action eq "link" ) {

        # hack around potential race conditions -- will only be an issue during linking
        my $tries = 1;
        until ( $retCode == 0 or $tries == 0 ) {
            last if ( $retCode = system($cmd) ) == 2;      #compile error; stop trying
            $tries--;
        }
    }
    else {
        $retCode = system($cmd);
    }
    push( @retCodes, ( $retCode >> 8 ) );

    #testing
    if ( $retCode != 0 ) {
        print "\n\t\t*** ERROR IN $comp: $@ !! ***\n";
        print "\t\t*** Action: $cmd -->> Error Level: " . ( $retCode >> 8 ) . "\n";

        #exit(-1);
    }

    return $retCode;
}
```

Error that gets displayed:

> Use of uninitialized value $maxReturnCode in concatenation (.) or
>   string at C:\script.pl line 66,  line 415.

I can see from the first line of output though, that I get things like: `Return Code: 0` `Return Code: 0` `Return Code: 2` ..

Comment: You need to show us the entire program, not just selected parts of it.  Based on what you've showed us, you shouldn't have gotten past the call to `max @retCodes`.

Comment: Why shouldn't I have gotten past that line? Even with what I've shown, it seems like a valid call?

Comment: Do you have use strict?

Comment: @harmic Yes, I have `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: @toolic Hmm, very strange - it does print within the builder. But I just checked and confirmed that the *only* non-global space `retCodes` is accessed is during the builder method. I will update my question with the full builder method fwiw

Comment: The code you shows cannot possibly reach the line where you say it throws a runtime error. After adding the missisng line for your code to compile, it produces `Return Code: 0` and `Can't return outside a subroutine at x.pl line 19.` as I expected, not the behaviour you describe. The code you posted does not produce the output you say it does. Fix your code so it actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AndyLester: I would be much more comfortable if you weren't so abrupt. Please think about what advice *you* would like to read if you had the same problem. If nothing else, please avoid colloquial Americanisms

Comment: I've updated my question with more detail.

Comment: @MrDuk Your code does not currently validate.  There are unbalanced braces, so everything after the following line appears to be outside of a subroutine even though it ends in a `return` statement:  `print "\n\t\tReturn Code`

Comment: @Miller my mistake - I had left some extra code from my update. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the code isn't sharing the array between threads; so because of that, each thread is modifying it's local copy of the array, not the global array as expected. The fix for this problem is to share the variable, and lock it before accessing it during the thread processing:

```
my @retCodes;
share(@retCodes);

...

#during the thread sub
 lock(@retCodes);
 push(@retCodes, ($retCode>>8));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stubbed-out runnable version that you should be able to modify a bit to do what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'max';
use threads;

#global space
my @retCodes = ();
share(@retCodes);

sub builder {
  my ($comp, $cmd) = ('builder', 'test');
  for my $retCode (qw/0 0 256/) {
    print "\n\t\tReturn Code: " . ($retCode >>8) . "\n";
    lock(@retCodes);
    push(@retCodes, ($retCode>>8));
  }
}

#main
builder();
# other threads started...
# wait for threads to complete...

printf "Codes: %s\n", join(', ', @retCodes);
my $maxReturnCode = max(@retCodes);
print "Highest Error Code: $maxReturnCode\n"; #<-- crashes with error below

exit($maxReturnCode);
```

Comment: Why go to all the trouble of `eval`ing `die` when all you do is `print` the error?

Comment: And `exit($maxReturnCode) unless $maxReturnCode == 0; exit(0);` is exactly the same as `exit $maxReturnCode;`. Your code is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: I attempted to keep as much of the OP's (now edited) code as possible, so they might understand my answer more easily.

Comment: I don't see `eval { die "string" };` anywhere in the OP's code. Anyway, why does SO have to be garbage in, garbage out? The OP could learn a lot from seeing well-written, idiomatic code in an answer.

Comment: Cleaned up a bit, and modified to include the actual answer, instead of providing a runnable example to help with debugging, a la http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code